# How do I get a Cursor row with a certain value

Tags: android, sql, kotlin

I have

```
var profileDatabase: SQLiteDatabase
```

I need to use it to get a Cursor with just the row I want with all the columns in it

If I have data like

| name | age | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | 12 | White |
| John | 13 | Blue |

I just want to get the Cursor with

| name | age | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | 12 | White |

My Idea would be to do the following

```
val cursor = profileDatabase.query("profile_table", null, "the_column_i_want_to_check_if_it_has_a_string",
                "a_string_to_check_for", null, null, null) 
// Like so

val cursor = profileDatabase.query("profile_table", null, "name",
                "Sam", null, null, null)
```

However the input where **Sam** is is requiring a  Array<String!>. I tried `arrayof("Sam")` but I get

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

So how do I properly get the Cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this

```
 Cursor cursor;
 String[] columns = {"name", "age", "color"};
 cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("profile_table", columns, "name=?", new String[]{"Sam"}, null, null, null);
 if (cursor != null) {
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 }
```

Comment: Hmm let me investigate further... Cursor.movetofirst seems to take care of when I have A single row

Comment: Yep this was insightful I think the problem had also been me catering for an empty table